# Java Script Works Properly (no Horizontal Scrolling) on Desktop, but on Mobile extends far beyond viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am currently working on www.kylehoard.com (it's live).  On my desktop (macbook air 13), the responsive navigation menu works as it should, and Smoothdivscroll (jQuery plugin to handle image gallery, located here http://smoothdivscroll.com) looks as it should.

The div containing the images should be 100% width, and the images should be horizontally scrollable (they are correctly working on the desktop version).

On my mobile (iPhone 6, evo 4g lte), div containing the images extends past the viewport.  Instead of being 100% width of the phone, you can manually scroll sideways for seemingly forever. Because of this, the width of the page longer than it should be, so the responsive menu doesn't show up.

- I know that javascript/jquery are working, as they work on the desktop and the plugin does initially load (just incorrectly).
- I added the meta viewport tag inside the head tag of my html page.

I have it narrowed to smooth scroll div, but I'm confused as to why the problem would only occur on a mobile device and not the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how you narrowed the source of the issue to the smoothdivscroll package. It might help if you provided more information on that topic.

In any event, you may find it useful to employ the `<meta viewport ../>` tag, which assists with scaling on screens with different form factors. It is especially useful for designing responsive pages that display properly on mobile devices.

I suggest you set the viewport and tell us what happens. For starters, try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For further reading, see [Google's recommendations for setting viewport for mobile-ready pages](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport) and [Mozilla's guide to configuring the viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry I will clarify as best I can.  I did add the meta viewport tag (inside the head of my html document).  The problem is that on a mobile phone (I invite you to visit kylehoard.com and see), the images extend past the visible area. The entire div should be 100% width, but be horizontally scrollable.  The confusing part to me is that the div breaks on a mobile phone, but not the desktop.

Comment: Well, glad we made some progress. Right now it looks like you added the <meta viewport.../> tag inside the frameset, but not at the top level - try putting it at the top level html file. Then please post the code that you're using to configure the div.

Comment: What exactly is the "top level html file"?  The website consists of 8 php pages.  I placed the meta viewport tag inside the head tag of the landing page (the page I'm testing).  ------ about smoothdivscroll ---- is there a way to upload my javascript and css to this website? Sorry I am very new to this.  But to make the story short, there is absolutely no javascript that detects a mobile vs desktop.  My only media queries are my navigation bar hides and a mobile one pops up when the screen is below 640 px...but I feel like it is still doing device pixels because my iPhone 6 shows the desktop.

Comment: 1. Go to [link](kylehoard.com)
2. View source
Do you see a `<meta viewprt .../>` tag? Because I don't.

Comment: Sorry to keep dragging this along... I appreciate your help.  When I go to KyleHoard.com, I select Develop > Show Page Source, I notice that my webpage is not actually being displayed.  There's a <frameset> tag, and inside the framset is the ip address to the original html code (that has the meta viewport tag)...I don't remember configuring this, nor do I understand it.  Thank you again for your help.  EDIT - I'm reading into this, and I guess it has to do with my "Domain masking" through GoDaddy.  Thank you for getting me this far.

Comment: Interesting. Let me know if you figure out a way to configure what GoDaddy is doing.